# Как возвести число в степень

Tags: c++, c

((a + b + c)*pi)^2

Как возвести в степень это выражение на языке СИ?

Comment: Умножить на себя же. Вариант хуже - использовать функцию `pow`.

Comment: Чем же плоха функция pow?

Comment: По нынешним временам для float что умножение, что pow отправляются в сопроцессор с плавающей точкой. А вот что быстрее делается в сопроцессоре с плавающей точкой - умножение или pow это вопрос интересный.

Comment: Хотя бы потому что *в общем случае* это вызов функции. Вариант с целочисленной степенью в стандарте вроде бы отсутствует, так что опять же в общем случае это будет вычисление менее эффективное...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <math.h>

float y=pow((a+b+c)*pi,2);
```